# PHP SOAP Client for Complex XML Request

Tags: php, soap-client

I am trying to create a request using the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<VertexEnvelope xmlns="urn:vvvvvvvv:o-series:tps:8:0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:vvvvvvv:o-series:tps:8:0 vvvvvv_Envelope.xsd">
         <Login>
            <UserName>xxxxxxx</UserName>
            <Password>xxxxxxxx</Password>
         </Login>
         <QuotationRequest documentDate="2018-02-07" transactionType="SALE">
  <Currency isoCurrencyCodeAlpha="USD"/>
  <Seller>
    <Company>2</Company>
    <Division>340</Division>
  </Seller>
  <Customer>
    <Destination taxAreaId="230132823">
      <City>BARAGA</City>
      <MainDivision>MI</MainDivision>
      <PostalCode>49908-9204</PostalCode>
    </Destination>
  </Customer>
  <LineItem lineItemNumber="1">
    <Seller>
      <PhysicalOrigin taxAreaId="261835449">
        <City>ST. CHARLES</City>
        <MainDivision>MO</MainDivision>
        <PostalCode>63301</PostalCode>
      </PhysicalOrigin>
    </Seller>
    <Customer>
      <CustomerCode classCode="20683"/>
    </Customer>
    <Product productClass="143"/>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <UnitPrice>6.95</UnitPrice>
    <FlexibleFields>
      <FlexibleCodeField fieldId="7">SP STD</FlexibleCodeField>
    </FlexibleFields>
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem lineItemNumber="2">
    <Customer>
      <CustomerCode classCode="20683"/>
    </Customer>
    <Product productClass="276"/>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <UnitPrice>2</UnitPrice>
  </LineItem>
</QuotationRequest>
</VertexEnvelope>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am using the WSDL method.

I am setting a variable `$xml` to the "xml" above.

The the bulk of the remaining code is:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                                        'trace' => true,
     'ssl'   => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
      ),
      'Login' => array (
                 'UserName' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
                 'Password' => 'xxxxxxx',
      ),
                                      ));


$client->__setLocation('https://vvvvvvvv.yyyyyyyyy.com/vvvvvv-ws/services/CalculateTax80');


    $args = array(new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML));
    echo "<hr>args<br>";
    print_r($args)."<br><br>";

    print "<br><br>";

    #  var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
    $obj = $client->calculateTax80($xml);
    print "var dump obj:<br><br>";
    var_dump($obj);
    #print "var dump getLastRequest<br><br>";
    #       var_dump($client->getLastRequest());
    print "<br><br>";
```

The output I am getting is:

```
args
Array ( [0] => SoapVar Object ( [enc_type] => 147 [enc_value] =>  username password  2 340  BARAGA MI 49908-9204   ST. CHARLES MO 63301    1 6.95 SP STD    1 2      ) )
```

And the error info is:

```
string(9) "SoapFault" object(SoapFault)#5 (10) { ["message":protected]=> string(30) "java.lang.NullPointerException" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(50) "/soapservices/xxxxxx05.php" ["line":protected]=> int(103) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(50) "//soapservices/xxxxxx05.php" ["line"]=> int(103) ["function"]=> string(6) "__call" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "calculateTax80" [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1570) " xxxxxxxx xxxxxx  2 340  BARAGA MI 49908-9204   ST. CHARLES MO 63301    1 6.95 SP STD    1 2     " } } } [1]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(50) "/var/www/html/ecommerce/soapservices/testphp05.php" ["line"]=> int(103) ["function"]=> string(14) "calculateTax80" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1570) " xxxxxxx xxxxx  2 340  BARAGA MI 49908-9204   ST. CHARLES MO 63301    1 6.95 SP STD    1 2     " } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["faultstring"]=> string(30) "java.lang.NullPointerException" ["faultcode"]=> string(14) "soapenv:Server" ["detail"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["vvvvvException"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["exceptionType"]=> string(20) "NullPointerException" ["rootCause"]=> string(30) "java.lang.NullPointerException" } } }
```

Comment: Can you check the serverside logs? Also what does "I am using the wsdl method" mean?

Comment: If you have an entire SOAP message you should post it as if it was a REST XML document. That is your best bet

Comment: It seems to me that the SOAP server is a Java application and there is a bug in it which leads the exception about using a NULL pointer. Please first check the server code, it is quite possible for your PHP code to not have a bug.

Comment: I do not have access to the serverside logs.  Regarding "WSDL" method:  Many of the sites I have been searching to find an answer refer to the use of the WSDL url in the SoapClient call as the "WSDL" method vs null and defining the connection in the parms. -- feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I set-up a test in SOAPUI and it works after modifying the location to https.//  The WSDL refers to http://